# Recover lost files on external hard drive after scan and repair

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Seagate 1 TB external harddrive. I plugged it into my laptop and it said there was an issue preventing it from running properly. I clicked on the notification and it gave me the option to "scan and repair" the harddrive. I clicked it and it took about 1 minute and then said it was ready to use.

However upon further investigation I found that a folder containing approx. 1000 .mp3 files was gone. I tried searching for the folder name, and names of the files in the folder on the harddrive but had no luck. I tried looking at the properties of the folders to find and previous versions and there were none. It was pretty much as if they had just vanished. I tried a some free recovery software with no results. I am still in the process of trying others but I don't see a good outcome.

I also tried talking to the tech support from the company who made the harddrive but they were really no help. They just asked what happened and I told them everything that I have typed in here this far. What can I do to get these files back? Are they gone forever? What happened to them?

I am also using Windows 10.

Comment: Did you have a backup?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you download the HDD manufacturer's brand-specific diagnostic tool, @Eric and test the health and SMART status of your external drive. I hope you have a backup of the files stored on the drive, otherwise you  might need a professional data recovery assistance to get your files back. :(  I'd also suggest you check how the HDD appears in another computer and also using a different USB cable. Check if you have [all folders on the drive UN-hidden](http://www.wikihow.com/Unhide-Folders-in-Windows-7) as well. Hope it helps. Good luck!